# What's the behavior of limits of greatest integer functions when the numbers are negative?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove that $\lim_{x\to 2}$$[[x]]+[[-x]]$ exists, and to do that I have to prove that right-and left-hand limits are the same, so I have done this:

$$\text{Left-Hand}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 2^-}[[x]]+[[-x]]$$ 
$$\lim_{x\to 2^-}[[x]]+\lim_{x\to 2^-}[[-x]]$$
$$\lim_{x\to 2^-}[[2]]=1 \lim_{x\to 2^-}[[-2]]=-3$$ 
$$1+-3=-2$$

$$\text{Right-Hand}$$
$$\lim_{x\to 2^+}[[x]]+[[-x]]$$
$$\lim_{x\to 2^+}[[x]]+\lim_{x\to 2^+}[[-x]]$$
$$\lim_{x\to 2^+}[[2]]=2 \lim_{x\to 2^+}[[-2]]=-2$$
$$2+-2=0$$

The right-and left-hand limits are supposed to be the same for $\lim_{x\to 2}$$[[x]]+[[-x]]$ to be true, and the problem I am doing says that this is supposed to be true. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the LHL ,by $x=2-h$ so that $h \to 0$ where $h$ is positive. ,similarly RHL by $x=2+h$ where $h$ is positive. Both gives $-1$ i think, just rough mental work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your working doesn't really make sense. *Mann*'s comment is roughly right but you should write down a rigorous version. For example you wanted to prove:

$\lim_{x \to 2^-} [x] = 1$ and $\lim_{x \to 2^-} [-x] = -2$.

To do so note that:

( $[x] = 1$ and $[-x] = -2$ ) for any $x \in (1,2)$

Similarly to get the other two limits:

( $[x] = 2$ and $[-x] = -3$ ) for any $x \in (2,3)$

In general you should split cases according to the discontinuities of the expression, and since you want the limit at $x = 2$ the only discontinuity that matters is the one at $x = 2$. All the other discontinuities are made irrelevant by choosing a sufficiently small neighbourhood of $2$.